# Event on-error in <img> is not working?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I using VueJS to code front-end and I have a problem with  tag when loading image.

```
Template
<div class="items" transition="fade" v-for="item in list">
    <img :src="item.logoPath" @error="replaceByDefault">
</div>

JS(ES6)
export default {
    methods: {
        replaceByDefault(e) {
             // code here to replace image by default
        }
    }

    template: require('./template.html')
}
```

Currently, I had debug in replaceByDefault function but it's not run into this function? I don't know why?

Could you help me explain this problem?  thanks!

Answer (score 34):

I tried to do something similar to this but my problem was that I getting 404 on some of the images and I wanted to replace the image with a default image.

this is my solution:

```
<template>
<div :key="index" v-for="(item, index) in list">
  <img :src="item.logo" @error="replaceByDefault">
</div> 
</template>

<script>
import img from '<<URL>>'
export default {
  methods: {
    replaceByDefault(e) {
      e.target.src = img
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered a similar problem, my solution is the following code snippet, I know this solution is certainly not the best, but if your situation is very urgent, such as me, you can use the following solutions, let us Together looking for a better solution to appear

```
 <img onerror="javascript:this.src='error.png'">
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, last night I just wanted to solve the problem as soon as possible, I also know that this is not the best solution

Answer (score 2):

Thank everybody read this my problem, I resolved this problem :).

The reason on-error event does not work is because the property 'logoPath' of {item} object does not exist, so, the ':src' in vueJS is not bind to  and that src of image does exist => on-error does not work :)

My bad :(

Answer (score 1):

I've used different ways to solve the problem but it hasn't worked for me.
after that I've imported image address.
It works in vue3.

```
<template>
  <div :key="index" v-for="(item, index) in list">
    <img :src="item.imagelist" @error="errorImage">
  </div> 
</template>

<script setup>
import img from 'urlImage'
function errorImage(e) {
  e.target.src = img
 }
</script>
```